# slack interactive messages and jenkins general-webhook-plugin integration issue

Tags: jenkins, slack, jenkins-generic-webhook-trigger

I am integrating slack-interactive button with jenkins-generic-webhook-plugin to trigger jenkins job on button action by adding jenkins webhook url in slack's interactive response url. Issue is jenkins-generic-webhook-plugin  is not parsing requestBody sents by slack.
jenkins-generic-webhook-plugin supports payload request body only if the content-Type of invoke api is application/json,
But slack sends the payload with content-type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Is there a way by which either
jenkins-generic-webhook-plugin will work with content-type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded
or
slack interactive message response payload will send with content-Type as application/json,